# Add multi year average column to each row

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataset, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset of hourly temperatures, precipitation, and other numerical fields indexed by their timestamp going back 10 years.

I would like to add a 10 year "average" column for each respective field.

I was able to groupby month,day and thus get the respective means for each day but I don't know how to add these means back to the original dataframe.

Here is my code:

http://cl.ly/WWRn

http://cl.ly/WWJW

Any tips?

EDIT:

The answer below is correct if instead of converting to t.date you do:

```
    df['datetime'].apply(lambda t: "%d-%d" % (t.month, t.day) )
```

Comment: So do you want to have the same values for rows with the same data (year,month, day) ? Maybe you could `merge()` (like `join` in SQL) two dataframes if you had year,month,day in grouped data.

Comment: yes... that is exactly what what I would want... let me try that

Comment: The problem with that is that the grouped dataframe doesn't have the same number of indices... There is only one row for every day... while the original has a row for every hour....

Comment: `merge()` can do `left join` like SQL and should duplicate data from group  in rows in dataframe.

Comment: so I think thats close but the problem is they don't share the same indices... The first df is indexed by a hourly timestamp while the grouped one is I believe a multi-index... (first month then 31 days, second month then 31 days etc) See here http://cl.ly/WVqZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something like this - maybe it helps you (or not).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( [
    ['2011-01-01 01:00', 1, 2, 3],
    ['2011-01-01 02:00', 10, 20, 30],
    ['2011-01-01 03:00', 100, 200, 300],
    ['2011-01-02 01:00', 4, 5, 6],
    ['2011-01-02 02:00', 40, 50, 60],
    ['2011-01-02 03:00', 400, 500, 600],
], columns=['datetime','a','b','c'])

# convert string datetime to object datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

# now I have example dataframe for work

# create row with date only
df['date'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda t: t.date())

# groupe by date
g = df.groupby('date').mean()

# change `date` from index to normal column
g2 = g.reset_index()

# merge by `date` columns
new_df = pd.merge(left=df, right=g2, on='date', suffixes=('_df','_group') )

print df
print g
print g2
print new_df
```

df:

```
             datetime    a    b    c        date
0 2011-01-01 01:00:00    1    2    3  2011-01-01
1 2011-01-01 02:00:00   10   20   30  2011-01-01
2 2011-01-01 03:00:00  100  200  300  2011-01-01
3 2011-01-02 01:00:00    4    5    6  2011-01-02
4 2011-01-02 02:00:00   40   50   60  2011-01-02
5 2011-01-02 03:00:00  400  500  600  2011-01-02
```

g:

```
              a    b    c
date                     
2011-01-01   37   74  111
2011-01-02  148  185  222
```

g2:

```
         date    a    b    c
0  2011-01-01   37   74  111
1  2011-01-02  148  185  222
```

new_df:

```
             datetime  a_df  b_df  c_df        date  a_group  b_group  c_group
0 2011-01-01 01:00:00     1     2     3  2011-01-01       37       74      111
1 2011-01-01 02:00:00    10    20    30  2011-01-01       37       74      111
2 2011-01-01 03:00:00   100   200   300  2011-01-01       37       74      111
3 2011-01-02 01:00:00     4     5     6  2011-01-02      148      185      222
4 2011-01-02 02:00:00    40    50    60  2011-01-02      148      185      222
5 2011-01-02 03:00:00   400   500   600  2011-01-02      148      185      222
```

---

**EDIT:**

Using  `left_on='date', right_index=True` there is no need to use `reset_index()`

```
# change `date` from index to normal column
#g2 = g.reset_index() 

# merge by `date` columns
#new_df = pd.merge(left=df, right=g2, on='date', suffixes=('_df','_group') )
new_df = pd.merge(left=df, right=g2, left_on='date', right_index=True, suffixes=('_df','_group') )
```

print df

Comment: That's very close to what I want to do but it only takes the average for each unique day... I need the average for a day across all 10 years to be added on to each one of those respective days. For example say the average temp for June 23rd across all 10 years was 50 then I would like 50 to be on all the June 23rds for each year.

Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: So you have to change `df['date'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda t: t.date())` to get only day and month.

Comment: For example `df['date'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda t: "%d-%d" % (t.month, t.day) )`

Comment: YES! that worked!

df['date'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda t: "%d-%d" % (t.month, t.day) )